# Works on Firefox and Chrome; not on IE8

Tags: html, css, web, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am trying to create a very simple website using Kompozer. I have a horizontal menu that works fine in Chrome and FF but not in IE8.  The HTML for the menu is:

```
<div id="hmenu">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="Sounds.html">Sounds</a>
</li>
<li>Contact </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The relevant bits in the CSS are:

```
#hmenu {
  border-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 364px;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Bauhaus;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#hmenu *|ul {
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#hmenu *|li {
  border-style: none;
  color: #009999;
  float: left;
  width: 85px;
}
#hmenu *|a {
  border-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
#hmenu *|a:hover {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #66ffff;
```

I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to make this work on all three browsers.
Thank you.
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple css selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/nyxyh/5/

```
#hmenu {
  border-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 364px;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Bauhaus;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#hmenu ul {
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#hmenu ul li {
  border-style: none;
  color: #009999;
  float: left;
  width: 85px;
}
#hmenu ul li a {
  border-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
#hmenu ul li a:hover {
  border-style: none;
    background-color: #66ffff;
}
```

Comment: @Chris - accept answers if the solved the problem so others know that this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

IE usually will have these issues. What you can try to do (may be easier then trying to make all browsers work with the same css file) is to make a special css file for IE 8 only. To add that css file just use this code:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSForIE8.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/><![endif]-->
```

This will work only if IE 8 is the browser.

Comment: Thanks, it may come to that but I also just noticed the the "HTML checker" I used inserted this:  *|    all over the place.  Don't know why, but removing has sorted a lot of problems!